# How to pass Category Attribute value from REST API

Tags: rest, api, opentext, livelink

I am able to upload files or create node through the Content server(16.0.3) REST Api `(POST: api/v1/nodes)`.
But How do I pass Category Attribute value while uploading file to opentext Content server..

Because as per [DeveloperGuide](https://developer.opentext.com/webaccess/#url=%2Fawd%2Fresources%2Fapis%2Fcontent-server-v2%23!%2Fnodes%2FcreateNode_post_16&tab=501) there are only 3 parameters that I can pass

```
type,parent_id,name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a category to node, need to pass **roles** with Category,  Category Attribute values in Json formate.For example node (20589) has category with name BillingCat(42069) contains ReferenceID (42069_2) then pass parameters as below

> ```
>   type: 144,
>     parent_id: 20589,
>     name: file.name,
>     roles: {
>       categories: {
>         {
>           '42069': { // category (42069)
>             '42069_2': 'ABC23' //attribute value
>           }
>         }
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to make a second post after node has been created:
POST api/v1/nodes/{id}/categories

Hope this helps

Comment: That's to add a category to a node.  I don't think that is the same as giving a node's category a value.

Comment: I see. Have a look at the put method api/v1/nodes/{id}/categories/{category_id}/ (Updates attributes values on the specified category and node)

Comment: What if the Attribute is Required Field..Then you cant upload the file with out specifying that